# PHP, phpMyadmin | Как удалить данные из таблицы mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, таблицы

Где ошибка в коде? Не выводит nice на странице + не удаляет данные из таблицы.
Код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>cdel</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("ne_pakazhu", "ne_pakazhu_cbase", "ne_pakazhu", "ne_pakazhu_cbase");
  $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno){
  $json_array = array("error" => 1, "message" => "Ошибка подключения к БД");
  $json = json_encode($json_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
  exit($json);
  }
  else {
    if (isset($_GET['que'])) {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM `cbase` WHERE `que`=".$_GET['que'];
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            {
        echo "nice";
    }
            }
  }
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос прошу закрыть. Решение проблемы: Немного изменить часть кода. Код той самой части:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `cbase` WHERE `que`='" . $_GET['que'] . "'";
```